# How to add Assertion in JSR223 using java

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

How to add assertion on response message in jsr223 postprocessor using java code.

I tried using `AssertionResult.setFailure(true);` but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) instead JSR223 PostProcessor

> JSR223 Assertion allows JSR223 script code to be used to check the status of the previous sample.

You are missing calling [setFailureMessage](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

```
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Your reason for failure");
```

> The script can check various aspects of the `SampleResult`. If an error is detected, the script should use `AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("message")` and `AssertionResult.setFailure(true)`.

Comment: This is for groovy right? i am using JAVA for scripting and if i use this command in java i am getting  get Exception error "javax.script.ScriptException:"

Comment: @SadhaNanda this is Java, show your full error details

Comment: Below are the screenshot of error msg
![Err 1](https://eastceylon.com/image/aXkw5).  
![Err 2](https://eastceylon.com/image/aXfoE).

Comment: @SadhaNanda you should change to  JSR223 Assertion (updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
def expectedMessage = 'some expected message'
def actualMessage = prev.getResponseMessage()

if (expectedMessage != actualMessage) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
}
```

Should do the trick for you, in the above example `prev` stands for **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Also get used to look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it might be the case your script fails somewhere somehow

Comment: Hi Bro thanks for your reply but i am looking solution for Java not for Groovy

Comment: There is no `Java` in JSR223 Assertion, what you think of "java" is [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) and [according to JMeter Best Practices you should not be using it for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)